# Spring Security not authorizing

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've been following a guide but I can't get `Spring Security` to work.
It looks like it is authenticating but not authorizing or viceversa, or not redirecting to the login successful page. Maybe it is a stupid mistake but I can't see it.

My spring security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { 
        "/webjars/**", 
        "/css/**", 
        "/js/**", 
        "/images/**", 
        "/",
        "/about/**", 
        "/contact/**", 
        "/error/**/*",
        "/h2-console/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        // Required by h2 console to work
        if(activeProfiles.contains("dev")) {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/payload")
            .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService);   
    }    
}
```

**The application-dev.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**The logs:**

> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@2dafa81d: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId:     0D60174BBA25377F65443D95DB72F713; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7a27baf6, returned: 1
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
>
> DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /js/scripts.js reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: The authentication process does throw an error. Although being downvoted (wasn't me, although reasonable), I think the question/problem might be useful especially for those coming from spring-security <=4. However, the question misses the problem description and could use some cleanup as almost all of the information provided does not help in understanding the problem at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During authentication the application throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
```

This exception is thrown, because the (plain text) password provided is missing the password-encoder `{id}`-prefix. Spring Security 5 now stores passwords using the following format (this was not the case for previous versions of spring security):

```
{id}encodedPassword
```

So that means for plain-text passwords, the `{noop}` id tells spring to match passwords using a `NoOpPasswordEncoder` (which basically handles passwords as plain-text).

However, storing plain-text passwords is highly discouraged (although it might be useful for automated testing).

#### Use a password encoder instead

Use of a `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder` or `SCryptPasswordEncoder` is highly recommended.

**BCryptPasswordEncoder**

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // Create an encoder with strength 31
        // values from 4 .. 31 are valid; the higher the value, the more work has to be done to calculate the hash
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    ...

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

**Encoding the password**

```
@Service
class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }    

    User createUser(String username, String password) {
        // encrypt the plain-text password
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        User user = new User(username, encodedPassword));
        //...
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

---

#### Supporting more than one encoder

To support more than one encoder, one might want to look at the [`DelegatingPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html) and [`PasswordEncoderFactories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.html).

For further details have a look at https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format